# Need to send email to multiple reciepent from filter data

Tags: excel, vba, email

[image]I wanted to send email to multiple recipient as per their fund code. for eg. in given image I want email for QR fund in column A to be sent out to B2,B3 and B4 in same email and subject line should be "C2" for next I want email for RTIO fund in column A to be sent out to B5, B7 and B8 in same email and subject line should be "C5" and so on

```
Sub SendMultipleEmails()

Dim Mail_Object, OutApp As Variant


 With ActiveSheet
lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).Row
End With

For i = 2 To lastrow

Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutApp = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

With OutApp
 .Subject = "Your subject here"
 .Body = "Your message here"
 .To = Cells(i, 2).Value
 .dISPLAY
 End With
```

I am not able to apply filter condition and get multiple email recipient in one email

Comment: Is this the Full Code ?

Comment: Yes, this is full code as it is creating individual email. I want only one email for each fund and all receipts of that fund to be in "To"

Comment: Well you can Loop through and draft mails.

Comment: Yes but I am not sure how to apply code for loop

Comment: Can you sort according to Column A so that the same funds are grouped together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code:**

```
Sub SendMultipleEmailsaa()

Dim Mail_Object, OutApp As Object
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet
Dim arr() As Variant

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "b").End(xlUp).row

arr = ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow)

Set Mail_Object = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

first = 2

For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)


    If i = UBound(arr) Then GoTo YO
    If arr(i + 1, 1) = arr(i, 1) Then
                first = WorksheetFunction.Min(first, i + 1)
    Else
YO:
    Set OutApp = Mail_Object.CreateItem(0)

    With OutApp
         .Subject = ws.Range("C" & i + 1).Value
         .Body = "Your message here"
         .Display
         .To = ws.Range("A" & i + 1).Value
         For j = first To i
            .Recipients.Add ws.Range("A" & j).Value
         Next
         first = i + 2

    End With
    End If

Next

End Sub
```

---

**To automatically sort add this code below the calculation on LastRow in above code:**

```
ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=ws.Range("A2:A" & LastRow), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ws.Sort
    .SetRange ws.UsedRange
    .Header = False
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

---

**Another Update:**

```
Dim bc As String
With OutApp
     .Subject = ws.Range("C" & i + 1).Value
     .Body = "Your message here"
     .Display
     bc = ws.Range("A" & i + 1).Value
     For j = first To i
        bc = bc & ";" & ws.Range("A" & j).Value
     Next
     .BCC = bc
     first = i + 2

End With
```

Comment: Hi Thank you code is working fine and able to create three email draft however for last one getting run time error subscript our of range. and also need to sort data before running macro.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help sir, code is applying filter now however while creating last email draft I am getting a Run-Time error 9 - subscript out of range.    If WorksheetFunction.IfError(arr(i + 1, 1), "Z") = arr(i, 1) Then

Comment: Hi @khyatidedhia ... That's alright. I have corrected the code in the Answer. You are still using the  Previous Version!! Copy the complete code now and replace in your module. Don't go changing only one line, because changes were done in the middle of code as well.

Comment: Yuppiee.. :) Thank a lot sir.. its working fine now

Comment: Hello Sir, can we add all the recipient into "BCC" instead of "TO"?

Comment: Yes You can @khyatidedhia

Comment: I tried to using .BCC = ws.Range("A" & i + 1).Value instead .To = ws.Range("A" & i + 1).Value
 but it only picking up 1st recipient into BCC and other into "TO"

Comment: Because of this line `.Recipients.Add ws.Range("A" & j).Value` it adds to `.To`

Comment: Yes. is there any other way to add all email address into .BCC instead of .To

Comment: @khyatidedhia ,,Why would you redact the Accepted Answer ?

Comment: my apologies, it was clicked by mistake sir, I wanted to up vote the answer as it really help me a lot and wanted to appreciate your work as much as possible

Comment: Haha .. Alright. I just wanted to know the Reason. All the Best with your Future Coding Adventures 

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Main()
    Dim rngSource As Range: Set rngSource = ExpandRange(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2"))
    ReadDataAndSendAllMail rngSource
End Sub

Public Function ExpandRange(rngTopLeftCell As Range) As Range
    With rngTopLeftCell.Worksheet
        Set ExpandRange = rngTopLeftCell.Resize( _
            .Cells(.Rows.Count, rngTopLeftCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row - rngTopLeftCell.Row + 1, _
            .Cells(rngTopLeftCell.Row, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - rngTopLeftCell.Column + 1)
    End With
End Function

Public Sub ReadDataAndSendAllMail(rngSource As Range)
    Dim dctData As Dictionary: Set dctData = ReadData(rngSource)
    SendAllMail dctData
End Sub

Public Function ReadData(rngSource As Range) As Dictionary
    Dim dctResult As Dictionary: Set dctResult = New Dictionary
    Dim rngRecord As Range: For Each rngRecord In rngSource.Rows
        Dim dctRecord As Dictionary: Set dctRecord = New Dictionary
        dctRecord.Add "Fund", rngRecord.Cells(1, 1).Value
        dctRecord.Add "Email", rngRecord.Cells(1, 2).Value
        dctRecord.Add "Subject", rngRecord.Cells(1, 3).Value
        dctRecord.Add "Attachment", rngRecord.Cells(1, 4).Value
        If Not dctResult.Exists(dctRecord("Fund")) Then
            dctResult.Add dctRecord("Fund"), New Collection
        End If
        dctResult(dctRecord("Fund")).Add dctRecord
    Next rngRecord
    Set ReadData = dctResult
End Function

Public Sub SendAllMail(dctData As Dictionary)
    Const cstrEmailDelimiter As String = "; " ' Note: Observe which delimiter your local version of Outlook uses and replace this value with it
    Dim moaOutlook As Outlook.Application: Set moaOutlook = New Outlook.Application
    Dim varFund As Variant: For Each varFund In dctData.Keys
        Dim strFund As String: strFund = vbNullString
        Dim strTo As String: strTo = vbNullString
        Dim strSubject As String: strSubject = vbNullString
        Dim strBody As String: strBody = vbNullString
        Dim strAttachmentPath As String: strAttachmentPath = vbNullString
        Dim dctRecord As Dictionary: For Each dctRecord In dctData(varFund)
            strFund = dctRecord("Fund")
            strTo = strTo & cstrEmailDelimiter & dctRecord("Email")
            strSubject = dctRecord("Subject")
            strBody = vbNullString ' Note: Replace vbNullString with some text for the message body
            strAttachmentPath = dctRecord("Attachment")
        Next dctRecord
        strTo = Mid(strTo, Len(cstrEmailDelimiter) + 1)
        SendMail moaOutlook, strTo, strSubject, vbNullString, strAttachmentPath
    Next varFund
    moaOutlook.Quit
End Sub

Public Sub SendMail(moaOutlook As Outlook.Application, strTo As String, strSubject As String, strBody As String, strAttachmentPath As String)
    Dim omiMailItem As Outlook.MailItem: Set omiMailItem = moaOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
    With omiMailItem
        .To = strTo
        .Subject = strSubject
        .Body = strBody ' Note use .HTMLBody if you want to send an HTML email
        .Attachments.Add strAttachmentPath
        .display ' Note: If you want to manually press the send button, otherwise comment out this line
'        .send ' Note: If you want to automatically send it, uncomment this line
    End With
End Sub
```

I hope the function names make it easier to understand and reuse. I tested it, and worked for me.